# 2 labels with leading alignment and different font sizes

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have 2 labels on top of each other inside of a UIView. Top one is leading aligned to superview = 0 and the bottom one is leading aligned to the top one. As you can see they have different font sizes, textStyles and weights, which I think is the issue.

```
UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption1, weight: .regular)
UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body, weight: .semibold)
```

[image: vertically stacked labels, top is the label and bottom is the partially censored address]

In some cases, I think when the semibold label begins with a number, it gets slightly indented. I've seen a lot of answers fixing labels next to each other but not this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the implementation of the method `UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: weight:)`? The vanilla UIFont class doesn't have it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot we have that. It's our helper method. Just sets the font and preferred font.

Comment: I tried reproducing the issue but I couldn't, so if you could provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that would be helpful. Also, if you open the view debugger, are the frames of the labels indeed aligned?

Comment: OMFG!! thanks to your tip about viewing the debugger, it looks like it's a data issue. after trimming leading spaces, it's all good. (I've spend hours on this) - Thank you!!